# The different between if statement and ternary operator

Tags: javascript, function

```js
function findBiggestFraction( a , b ) {
  a > b ? console.log("a: ", a): ("b: ", b);
}

var firstFraction = 3/4;
var secondFraction = 5/7;

findBiggestFraction(firstFraction, secondFraction); // a: 0.75
findBiggestFraction(7/16, 13/25); // b: 0.52
findBiggestFraction(1/2, 3/4); // a: 0.75


  

function findBiggestFraction( a , b ) {
  if (a > b) {
    console.log("a: ", a);
  } else {
    console.log("b: ", b);
  }
}

var firstFraction = 3/4;
var secondFraction = 5/7;

findBiggestFraction(firstFraction, secondFraction); // a: 0.75
findBiggestFraction(7/16, 13/25); // b: 0.52
findBiggestFraction(1/2, 3/4); // a: 0.75
```

when I run the first code block it only execute the first call. On the other hand for the second block, it runs all three.

Comment: If I run the snippet you pasted, it runs all the calls to the methods.

Comment: `: ("b: ", b);` isn't going to be treated as an argument list for `console.log`, you actually need to specify `console.log` before it

Comment: You're just missing the `console.log` part after the `:`: `a > b ? console.log("a: ", a): console.log("b: ", b);` `("b: ", b)` is a valid expression that doesn't do anything, and has nothing to do with the `console.log` in the *other* expression.

Comment: Maybe you meant to do `console.log(...(a > b ? ["a: ", a] : ["b: ", b]));`? No, you cannot put an arbitrary expression between a function reference and its arguments to produce a call.

Comment: Side note: It's the conditional operator. Yes, it's *a* ternary operator (an operator accepting three operands), and it's currently JavaScript's only ternary operator, but it may not be forever...

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `console.log` for b.

```
a > b ? console.log("a: ", a): console.log("b: ", b);
```

Answer (score 1):

With the ternary, you're never calling `console.log` when the condition is false. `("b: ", b)` evaluates to `b`, then you don't do anything with the result.

Roughly equivalent code using an if-statement would be

```
if (a > b) {
  console.log("a: ", a);
} else {
  ("b: ", b);
}
```

The mistake is arguably much clearer when you use the more verbose statement. Change the ternary line to

```
a > b ? console.log("a: ", a) : console.log("b: ", b);
```

Note that using a ternary to run side effects is generally regarded as bad practice. Either use the ternary inside of `console.log` to pick what argument to pass in, or use an if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

You're functions are not the same.  The first function only prints something if `a > b` is true.  The second function prints either way.

This is a caveat to using the ternary operator.  It's very helpful, but can be easy to miss details like you just did.

Summary: Both blocks run both functions, but the first block only prints ~half the time.